# Javascript Append and Add Selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I'm trying to add selected to the option value which is rendered already within the object, but the below is not adding selected to the option value even they are equal. Ignoring the adding selected, is it because after doing this with appending?

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var startFormat = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, "dd / MM / yyyy");
    var form = $("<form id='changeName'>" +
        "<h3 class='eventHeader'>Edit Event: " +startFormat+ " </h3>" +
        "</div></form>");

    form.append("<div class='controls'>" +
        "<label class='control-label' for='title'>Language: </label>" +
        "<select class='span3' id='lang' name='lang'>" +
        <?php foreach($languages as $language): ?>
        "<option value='<?=$language->id;?>'><?=$language->title;?></option>" +
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        "</select>" +
        "</div>");

    $("#lang option").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == calEvent.lang)
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    });
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry, i misclicked the enter, didn't understand i've posted until saw your comment

Comment: get the options as a javascript object/array then append them by jQuery

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
$(this).attr("selected","selected");
```

try using `.prop()`:

```
$(this).prop("selected", true);
```

#### Updates:

you can use `.done()` method and use `change` event instead:

```
form.append("<div class='controls'>" +
    "<label class='control-label' for='title'>Language: </label>" +
    "<select class='span3' id='lang' name='lang'>" +
    <?php foreach($languages as $language): ?>
    "<option value='<?=$language->id;?>'><?=$language->title;?></option>" +
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    "</select>" +
    "</div>").done(function(){
          $(document).on('change', "#lang", function(){
               $('option', this).each(function(){
                  if ($(this).val() == calEvent.lang)
                    $(this).prop("selected", true);
               });
          }).change();  //<------fire the change event here when appended in dom
    });
```

Comment: same, nothing changes.

Comment: gives error with the done function, i think it can be applied with ajax things or not ?

Answer (score 0):

this is just an example:

```
<?php
$array = array('lang1' => 'option1', 'lang2' => 'option2');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="a_select"></select>
        <script>
            $(function() {

                var select_keys = [<?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) {echo "'$key', ";} ?>];
                var select_values = [<?php foreach ($array as $value) {echo "'$value', ";} ?>];

                $(select_values).each(function(i, item) {
                    var option = $('<option>'+ item +'</option>');
                    option.attr('value', select_keys[i]);
                    $('#a_select').append(option);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

update: key values is added.

you may load this values from another script with ajax, that's gonna be easier & cleaner.